# how to change property of color..font...datetimepicker

Tags: c#

how to change property of color..font...datetimepicker...

i remember that it can do with set and get....

can i get any sample ?

thank's

Comment: ¿Did you check the properties window panel? ¡Use the same names in your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to add another property to the datetimepicker, you will have to create your own control implementation that inherits datetimepicker. Then you can add a property to it.
Then override the Draw method, if the property has something to do with the presentation and handle the drawing on your own.

[Doc and Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Of the top of my head:

```
 dateTimePicker.ForeColor = Color.Green;


 dateTimePicker.CalendarForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: i mean that i whant to add some property to datatimepicker

Comment: @Gold: That is not what you are asking for in your question. Your are clearly asking how to set font foreground color.

Comment: sorry if i was incomprehensible
english is not my mother tongue

Comment: No downvote but this doesn't work: "Setting the ForeColor property has no effect on the appearance of the DateTimePicker control." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7we8k9a0.aspx - ditto for the backcolor property.

Comment: for future readers developing for post-WinXP: When Aero is enabled and used, even the CalendarForeColor has no effect. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.calendarforecolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx